# What is the use of callback using function pointer when it can be done in a normal way?

Tags: callback, function-pointers

I am new to programming.  I was not able to understand the use of call back by function pointer clearly.  Please help me to understand where actually the function pointers are needed.  I have given two examples. One callback using function pointer and other the normal way(Function calling a function).  Forgive me if it appears silly.

```
#include<stdio.h>

 void A()
{
     printf("Hello");
}

void B(void(*ptr)())
{
    ptr();
}

int main
{
    void (*p)() = A;
    B(p);
}
```

Another method

```
#include<stdio.h>

 void A()
 {
    printf("Hello");
 }

  void B()
  {
     A();
  }

 int main
 {
     B();
 }
```

What is the use of callback using function pointer when this can be achieved in a simpler way?

Comment: In the second, `B()` need to know `A()` by name at compile time. Practically, a callback function can rarely meet either of those two requirements.

Comment: @user3528438 at compile time you mean?

Comment: @user3528438 this is basically answer to this question